# ¿ Como puedo convertir archivos .doc o .docx a .txt en Java?

Tags: java

Realizar un programa que lea cada uno de los estudiantes del archivo creado en txt y luego se escriba cada estudiante en un nuevo archivo con formato .doc

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Depues has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar esto, tienes disponible la API de apache POI, especialmente desarrollada para tratar documentos de microsoft.

Para más información y documentación, tienes su web oficial:
https://poi.apache.org/